# Add selectedItemCls to First Item of DataView ExtJS

Tags: css, extjs, extjs4, dataview

I have ExtJS Dataview with following template for its Items.

```
<div class="item-container">
    <div class="{itemCls}"></div>
    <span class="item-title">{title}</span>
</div>
```

Now, I have set `selectedItemCls` config with value `item-selected`, which is styled accordingly in my stylesheet. When I click on items in dataview, it works fine, and selected item is highlighted. But I want to have first item of my dataview be selected by default (and thus having `item-selected` class already added to it).

I tried to play around the dataview component in its `afterrender` event but I couldn't add active class to first item.

**Update**

Note that I want to maintain that toggle behavior of class, so when dataview is rendered and user clicks on other item, first item (on which `tab-selected` was added programmatically) is no longer highlighted and clicked item gets `tab-selected` class.

So far, I tried calling `dataview.selModel.select(dataview.Store.getAt(0))` within `afterrender` event, and surprisingly, it works while debugging (breaking execution in `afterrender` event and proceeding step-by-step) but it throws `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addCls' of null` if I try it without DevTools open. I believe it is due to event bubbling since `select()` also fires `itemclick` and `selectionchange` events internally (I might be wrong though).

P.S. Using Chrome for debugging.

How to attain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hacking around for more than an hour, I found the fix!

When using `afterrender` event, where DataView is technically not fully rendered on UI, calling `select()` will fire `itemclick` event but there's nothing on UI, so it would lead to the `TypeError` I was getting (I'm still not 100% sure if this is the exact reason for TypeError I got).

So I have two possible fixes for this, where I'd prefer 2nd fix.

**Option - 1**

Make called to `select()` *deferred* by a few Milliseconds.

```
listeners: {
    afterrender: function(dv) {
        Ext.defer(function() {
            dv.selModel.select(dv.store.getAt(0));
        }, 10); // Some small number for delay will do.
    }
}
```

**Option - 2 (Recommended)**

Use `viewready` event instead of `afterrender`.

```
listeners: {
    viewready: function(dv) {
        dv.selModel.select(dv.store.getAt(0));
    }
}
```

I've used 2nd option and it works perfectly, however, any better suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for=".">',
        '<div class="item-container {[xindex === 1 ? "item-selected" : ""]}">',
            '<div class="{itemCls}"></div>',
            '<span class="item-title">{title}</span>',
        '</div>'
    '</tpl>,
)
```

You could also try this:

```
listeners: {
    afterrender: function(dv) {
        dv.selModel.select(dv.store.getAt(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: But will that maintain the toggling behavior of class? i.e. when I select other item from the same list, it should remove `tab-selected` class from that first item.

Comment: You didn't mention that in the question, but I've added another possibility to the answer.  HTH.

Comment: Tried your second suggestion, doesn't work either, I've updated my question.